# Changing to manual IP causes no internet connection

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

I'm setting the same settings even same router/gateway but it always just disconnects me.  Setting back to DHCP with manual address then it goes back to normal with internet.

192.168.1.3 is the default gateway that is set in my router. i want to set my gateway to 192.168.1.1 but this `manually` setting just doesn't work.

EDIT: i'm running macos 10.14.6 and macbook pro 15 inch mid 2015 if these matter

[image]

[image]

Comment: "192.168.1.3 is the default gateway that is set in my router. i want to set my gateway to 192.168.1.1 " This isn't clear. You mean you have two potential gateways, or the router is advertising the wrong address? or you want to change the router's actual address… which must be done in the router, not locally.

Comment: I have 2 gateways. 2 isps. connected to a single router. 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.3, the default gateway that is set in the router is 192.168.1.3 so DHCP uses that.  but I want to use 192.168.1.1 on this device

Comment: @GeneSy: 2 isps and how come they have the same Class C IP with 1.1 and 1.3 under same subnet. If I am not wrong, your router IP is 1.3 and you should set 1.3 as a default gateway. Your router must have NAT the internet and to get 1.1 you should modify the setting in router.

Comment: this setup already works for us on all our devices except my macbook. i'm not gonna ask people to change just for me @udhy

Comment: @GeneSy: From your Mac, can you ping 192.168.1.1 when you are in DHCP ?

Comment: yes i can ping all ips in the network while doing all these methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. Although confusing because the UI for the IP configuration wasn't reflecting properly. I had to check my internet's ip using google to confirm that my internet was in fact changing.

```
route delete default
route add default 192.168.1.1
```